# In R-studio, how would go about repeating a for-loop using the same [i] until a specific condition is met?

Tags: r, for-loop, repeat

I am taking 5-min readings of temperature and wind speed with two separate Arduino. The 5-min readings will be stored as files on each Arduino's SD card. Data files from both Arduino will be drawn into Rstudio to be cleaned, combined, processed, visualized, and output to specific folders within the working directory. I want to automate the entire process so I've decided to use for-loops. A possible issue I foresee would occur when I try to pull the two data files into R, but one or both of the files do not exist yet. I assume an error would occur and bring the whole thing crashing down.

I want to know if I can check to see if the files exist, and if not, repeat the loop at the same level of [i] until it does. I have found solutions semi-close to my situation, but I plan to name files as a function of [i] as well. I realize this makes the whole thing very delicate, so if one of you R pros know of a simpler way to do this. I am all ears!!

Since I haven't generated the code yet, I'm not really looking for a straight forward answer. I have been searching for a solution the past couple days, but "keyword" searching is not one of my strengths. Can someone please direct me towards some literature that may cover this topic?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work:

```
for(i in 1:n_files){
  while(!file.exists("path_to_file.ext")){
    do nothing or wait a reasonable time with Sys.sleep()
  }
  your code right here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It may be up to a month before I am able to run my experiment, but I will definitely remember to come back and click the checkmark when it works out.